# parsing buffer data into struct

Tags: c++, hid

I'm trying to create a C# wrapper for a C++ code that reads data from an HID. The code I have been given is pretty straight forward but not complete. Data received from the device is read into the buffer as below:

```
pTmpBuf = (U8 *)calloc( InputReportByteLength, sizeof(U8));
if (ReadFile( hDevice, pTmpBuf, InputReportByteLength, &nRead, NULL))
{
memcpy(`pAppBuffer`, pTmpBuf + 1, nRead-1);
}
```

I want to parse the data in the `pAppBuffer` into the struct that is defined as follows:

```
struct BAYER_CONTOUR_REPORT
{
unsigned char reportID; // HID report ID
unsigned char checkSum; // checksum for hostID + deviceID + data
unsigned char hostID // host ID assigned by communications manager
unsigned char deviceID; // device ID assigned by communications manager
unsigned char length; // length of data in buffer
unsigned char data[60]; // data send with message
};
```

How can this be done? Any help or pointers is appreciated.

Comment: The pAppBuffer is in the same size as the struct?

Comment: Is your code C# or C++?

Comment: the code I have posted is C++

Comment: Can I simply parse the data by casting struct object onto the buffer?

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba Which type is pAppBuffer?

Comment: @MosheD it's an unsigned int of width of 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I simply parse the data by casting struct object onto the buffer?

You can do the `memcpy` to the `struct` with the incoming buffer, provided you're sure the the incoming buffer or contents are aligned to structure definition.

for example

```
struct abc {
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    char d[2];
};

int main() {

    char arr[5] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
    struct abc sa;
    memcpy(&sa, arr, 5);


    return 0;
}
```

Here `arr` is incoming buffer, and with `memcpy` all the contents are copied appropriately.

Similarly, in your code you can do the following

```
struct BAYER_CONTOUR_REPORT bcr;
memcpy(&bcr, pAppBuffer, sizeof(struct BAYER_CONTOUR_REPORT))
```

Again, please mind the caveats that you need to be absolutely sure that size of `struct struct BAYER_CONTOUR_REPORT` and `pAppBuffer` is exactly same and the information is aligned to your structure